# jqplot how to ger rid of null values

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I'm using primefaces 6.0 line chart component, which is based on **jqPlot**. In my charts I have **null** values, which I need because I'm making use of the `breakOnNull` plotting option, so the curves have breaks on the null points, but unfortunately the null "points" are being shown as string (see screenshot).[image]

So far I have tried to solve this setting the `hideZeros: true` option - no success. I also tried a simple custom `pointLabels` renderer:

```
this.cfg.seriesDefaults.pointLabels =
{
    show: true, 
    location: 's',
    formatString: '%.1f',
    formatter: function(format, val){ 
         console.log(val);
         return (val== null?"":val);}
}
```

but this doesn't work either since the `null` values are not being passed to it all, which I can not understand.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this work in plain jqPlot?

Comment: If you mean the code snippet above, it is inside of an extender function and since I don't use plain jqPlot I don't know if this code will work 1:1 otherwise.

Comment: PrimeFaces does not do a lot in this regard, besides generating the basic javascript for the chart, the data and add the 'extender' script. An example in plain jqplot should not be to difficult to create (make sure you try the same version as PF users first) and then you can be sure if the problem is purely jqplot related or that PF messes things up. In the latter case, I'm more than willing to start investigating, but not if it is a purely jqPlot thing. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `pointLabels divs` with jQuery `each` function and when detecting a `null` string, change it to be `null`.

Here is an example for the approach, this addition function to the `(document).ready` event will remove the text of the x-axis labels, after the chart has been created. With a similar apporach you can remove your required values from the corresponding divs:

```
  $('.jqplot-xaxis-tick').each(function(i,elem) {
        $(this).text(null);
    });
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/337afs1h/5/) with example for the x-axis labels being removed by the described approach.

Answer (score 0):

Tried checking if the null values are by accident 'null' strings by changing `return (val== null?"":val);}` to `return (val== 'null'?"":val);}`